# Telerik Grid - Export to CSV more columns than displayed on screen

Tags: asp.net, telerik

**Problem:**  How to display more columns in a Telerik grid than are displayed in the rendered grid?

eg I'd like to only display on the screen the Surname, but on dump to csv would like firstname too.

I've tried visible = false, and display = false on the GridBoundColumns, but then they don't come out on the csv.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="grdAuctions" runat="server" AllowAutomaticDeletes="True" AllowAutomaticUpdates="True"
        AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="odsAuctionSales"
        GridLines="None" EnableEmbeddedSkins="False" OnItemDataBound="grdAuctionSales_ItemDataBound">
        <ExportSettings HideStructureColumns="true" />
        <MasterTableView Width="100%" CommandItemDisplay="Top">
            <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced" />
            <CommandItemSettings ShowAddNewRecordButton="false" ShowRefreshButton="false" ShowExportToCsvButton="true"
                ExportToCsvImageUrl="~/Images/excel.jpg" ExportToCsvText="Export to csv" />
        </MasterTableView>
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="odsAuctionSales" CssClass="listItems"
            Width="98%">
            <SortExpressions>
                <telerik:GridSortExpression FieldName="Name"></telerik:GridSortExpression>
            </SortExpressions>
            <RowIndicatorColumn>
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
            </RowIndicatorColumn>
            <ExpandCollapseColumn>
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
            </ExpandCollapseColumn>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="Edit">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="edit" runat="server" Text="Edit"></asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NameOnTable" HeaderText="Name On Table" SortExpression="NameOnTable"
                    UniqueName="NameOnTable">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" SortExpression="Surname"
                    UniqueName="Surname">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Firstname" HeaderText="Firstname" SortExpression="Firstname"
                    UniqueName="Firstname">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

**Edit** Here is how I got it working

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == RadGrid.ExportToCsvCommandName)
        {
            grdAuctions.MasterTableView.GetColumn("Edit").Visible = false;
            grdAuctions.MasterTableView.GetColumn("DPSAuthCode").Visible = true;
    grdAuctions.MasterTableView.ExportToCSV();
        }

    }
```

and in the aspx

```
OnItemCommand="RadGrid1_ItemCommand"
```

and

```
 <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="DPSAuthCode" HeaderText="DPSAuthCode" Visible="false"
                    SortExpression="DPSAuthCode" UniqueName="DPSAuthCode">
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching the Visible or Display property value prior to the export call should do the trick. Check the relevant section (Hide Columns) [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-csv-export.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea i can give you is to have the control display it, and then use jquery to set the display on those columns off.

Another option might be to overload the export to csv function, but I am not familiar enough with this Telerik control to give you any pointers on that.